# Matrix multiplication using multiple locales

Tags: chapel

Hi I wanted to see if anyone can see any glaring problems with my code. I am trying to run my code over two Nvidia Jetson boards to utilize 8 cores for speed up. I want to compare the speed of using one board compared to two boards. I have the Chapel environment set up to be allowed for multiple locale execution.
Here is my implementation:

```
use LinearAlgebra, Norm, Random, Time;
var t : Timer;

writeln("Size of your matrix?");
var size = read(int);

var grid : [1..size, 1..size] uint(8);
var grid2 : [1..size, 1..size] uint(8);
var grid3 : [1..size, 1..size] int;

fillRandom(grid);
fillRandom(grid2);

t.start();
forall loc in Locales do
  on loc do
    forall i in 1..size do
        forall j in 1..size do
            forall k in 1..size do
                grid3[i,j] += grid[i,k] * grid2[k,j];
t.stop();
writeln("Done!:");
writeln(t.elapsed(),"seconds");
t.clear();
```

I keep getting:

```
error: Only 1 locale may be used for CHPL_COMM layer 'none'
To use multiple locales, see $CHPL_HOME/doc/rst/usingchapel/multilocale.rst
```

When I run the cores.chpl file which has:

```
coforall loc in Locales do
  on loc do
    writeln("locale ", here.id, " named ", here.name, " has ", here.numPUs(), " cores.");
```

This is the output:

```
locale 0 named JetsonNano has 4 cores.
locale 1 named JetsonNano2 has 4 cores.
```

So I know the environment is set up right.

I'm just not sure if I am setting my matrix multiplication code right for it be allowed over multiple locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message:

```
error: Only 1 locale may be used for CHPL_COMM layer 'none'
To use multiple locales, see $CHPL_HOME/doc/rst/usingchapel/multilocale.rst
```

indicates that when you compiled your Chapel program, you either had CHPL_COMM unset, or set to `none` in the session where the compilation took place.  Try setting `CHPL_COMM=gasnet` in your current session (or, equivalently, compiling with `--comm=gasnet`), recompiling, and then running with `-nl 2`.

Within a given session, you can run `$CHPL_HOME/util/printchplenv` to see what the current set and/or inferred environment variables are.  For a given Chapel program you can run `./myChapelProgram --about` to get information about the settings at the time it was compiled.

If you plan to work with `CHPL_COMM=gasnet` most of the time, you can use a [Chapel configuration files](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/usingchapel/chplenv.html#chapel-configuration-file) to avoid re-setting things over and over again.

Comment: ahhh okay that worked, I made a script that ran everything to set up the environment but for some reason it would skip ```CHPL_COMM=gasnet```. Now It won't allow me enter the size of the matrix. It just runs the whole code and gives me a time output without me ever entering the size of the matrix.

Comment: StackOverflow is not intended to be used for general ongoing conversations, but... the Chapeltastic way to get a size would be to use `config const size = 10` which will permit your program to be run as `myChapelProgram --size=100` or whatever size you want.  The puzzle about why reading the size isn't working should probably be taken to its own SO question or Chapel GitHub issue.